# Explode a string that has quotes in it

Tags: php, arrays, quotes, explode

I am looking to grab the data that is located in a string that looks like this:
`string(22) "width="16" height="16""`

I was hoping to use the explode function to grab the 16 and 16 values and place them into an array that i can use. But I don't know how to target the `$num` in the explode function in PHP. Usually I just have a comma that I can use.

Something like this but I know this is wrong:

```
$size = "width="16" height="16""
$sizes = explode('""', $size);
```

All this does is: `array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', 'width="16" height="16"', $matches);
$result = $matches[1];

/* print_r($result);
Array
(
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 16
)
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

explode() won't do this for you; it just splits a string on a constant delimiter (such as a comma), and what you need to do is extract text from between quotes. In this simple case, you can use preg_match_all() to do the job:

```
 $str = 'width="16" height="16"';
 preg_match_all('/\"(.*?)\"/', $str, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
```

returns

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => Array
     (
       [0] => "16"
       [1] => "16"
     )

   [1] => Array
     (
       [0] => 16
       [1] => 16
     )
 )
```

-- in other words, after the preg_match_all() call, $matches[1] contains an array of values matched by the pattern, which in this case is the attribute values you're after.

Comment: +1, for not using explode the old fashioned way. Not sure why you have the question mark in there, though, since there is already an asterisk. Maybe it should be outside of the parentheses?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this looks like a clean way of doing it with less code.

Comment: @johnrom: The question mark turns the * quantifier stingy; by default it will match as many characters as it can, which in this case would cause it to match '16" height="16' -- everything between the first quote mark in the string, and the last one. You may wish to improve your familiarity with Perl-compatible regular expressions, if this isn't something you've encountered before.

Comment: @AaronMiller I'm relatively familiar with Perl regex, but haven't needed to keep that particular use of the ? in mind because I typically use the above [^"] or [^>] syntax and have always been advised against trying to control regex greediness. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=24640

Comment: @johnrom, I find that a somewhat contrived example; in the supposedly imprecise regex using "(.*?)\?" , an unquoted question mark following the quoted one will produce the desired result, i.e., will capture text between the quotes, without a trailing question mark. I'd also note that PCRE engines have improved in the twelve years since that advice was given, as have processors, and that optimizing for readability is often preferable to optimizing for performance when no performance problem has yet been demonstrated.

Comment: @AaronMiller, PCRE engines have definitely improved... for both of our examples. I have found numerous examples of caret vs asterisk, and caret always seems to win. Provide counterexamples if you can because I'm genuinely interested. (I also find [^"] more readable.) In the following example, preg_match_all #1 uses .* and preg_match_all #2 uses [^] http://jeanbruenn.info/2011/09/10/regexp-vs-non-regexp-performance/

Comment: @johnrom: Thanks for proving my point for me! In the slowest test case described there, we're talking about a difference between ~100ns for [^...] vs. ~400ns for (.*?); by simple extrapolation from that test case, which given a constant regex should scale more or less linearly, we'd have to iterate ~750M times before we'd start seeing times >=1ms, and it'd take nearly a trillion iterations to get times expressible in whole seconds. When I talk about optimizing for readability, and worrying about performance only when it shows itself to be a problem, this is precisely what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Strange variable.

Either way, why not use a split command?

```
$size = 'width="16" height="16"';

$split_sizes = explode('"',$size);
$count = count($split_sizes);

for ( $i = 1; $i < $count; $i += 2) {
    $sizes[] = $split_sizes[$i];
}
```

The assumption here is that the string will only be populated with pairs of unquoted keys and double-quoted values.

Comment: perfect, just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$size = 'width="16" height="16" maxlength="200"';
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z\-]+)=/',$size,$fields);
preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z\-]+="([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)"/',$size,$values);
var_dump($fields[1]);
var_dump($values[1]);

// gives you
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "width"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "height"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "maxlength"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "16"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "16"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "200"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to select the values if they're going to be the only digits in the string (1234567890). [preg_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) will do such a thing - just make your "replacement" replace the matches with themselves (`'$1'`).

Answer (score 0):

How about getting rid of the double quotes and exploding on the space.  Then $sizes will look like:

```
{ 
    [0]=> width=16
    [1]=> height=16
}
```

You can then explode each slice of $sizes on the equals to get the values.

```
{
    [0] => width
    [1] => 16
}
{
    [0] => height
    [1] => 16
}
```

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
<?php

$size = 'width="16" height="16";
//get rid of all double quotes
$size = str_replace('"', '', $size);
$sizes = explode(' ', $size);
//show what is in the sizes array
print_r($sizes);
//loop through each slide of the sizes array
foreach($sizes as $val)
{
    $vals = explode('=', $val);
//show what is in the vals array during this iteration
    print_r($vals);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
explode("\"",$string);
```